# How to switch control from child window to parent window in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

- From Parent window I'm passing the control to child window
- I'm performing actions in the child window
- After performing, from a child window one more window will open(Child
  of 1st child window).
- I have to close both the child windows and have to get back to the
  Parent window.

  I'm not able to switch the control from child to parent window. I have tried out the below code

  ```
   String winHandleBefore = _driver.getWindowHandle();
  for(String winHandle : _driver.getWindowHandles()){
      _driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
  }

  String winHandleAfter = _driver.getWindowHandle();
  ```

  /*performing actions in the child window*/

  ```
  driver.close();
  _driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
  ```

Comment: Are you able switch the control to first child window?

Comment: Are you asking about the switching from 2nd child to 1st child window or from the Parent window to 1st Child window?

Comment: why can't you use window name to switch over? Is there any reason? Do you want to do any actions on the child of 1st child window?

Comment: I'm asking about transferring control from 2nd child window to 1st child window after closing the 2-child window ?

Comment: @Santoshsarma Yes. I'm able to transfer. But the problem is I'm not able to transfer it to parent from 1st Child window.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:

```java
 // Get Parent window handle
 String winHandleBefore = _driver.getWindowHandle();
 for (String winHandle : _driver.getWindowHandles()) {
   // Switch to child window
   driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
 }

// Do some operation on child window and get child window handle.
String winHandleAfter = driver.getWindowHandle();

//switch to child window of 1st child window.
for(String winChildHandle : _driver.getWindowHandles()) {
  // Switch to child window of the 1st child window.
  if(!winChildHandle.equals(winHandleBefore) 
  && !winChildHandle.equals(winHandleAfter)) {
    driver.switchTo().window(winChildHandle);
   }
 }

// Do some operation on child window of 1st child window.
// to close the child window of 1st child window.
driver.close();

// to close the child window.
driver.close();

// to switch to parent window.
driver.switchto.window(winHandleBefore);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

1. Close 2nd child window
2. Then there are two windows main window and 1st child window
3. Try to getWindowhandles(); it should return 2 window handles.
4. From that two window handles extract main window handle.
5. Switch back to main window using above window handle.

OR

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-switch-control-to-pop-up-window.html

Answer (score 0):

Too close multiple popups in WebDriver and switch to the parent window

```
String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
    
Set<String> pops=driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> it = pops.iterator();
    
while (it.hasNext()) {

    String popupHandle=it.next().toString();

    if(!popupHandle.contains(parent)){
        driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
        System.out.println("Popu Up Title: "+ driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle).getTitle());
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
before calling

```
driver.switchTo().window(parentwindow);
```

you should call

```
driver.switchto.defaultcontent .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            int i = WebDriver.WindowHandles.Count;
            if (i > 1)
            {
                //switch to child window
                WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(WebDriver.WindowHandles[1]);
                //switch to parent window
                WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(WebDriver.WindowHandles[0]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to switch to diff window handles and coming back to parent window

```
  String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
  for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
  {
  driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
  }
    for (String handle1 : driver.getWindowHandles())
 { 
  driver.switchTo().window(handle1);
 }
```

// your code here

```
 driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore); //switch to parent window
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String Parent_Window = driver.getWindowHandle();    

 for (String Child_Window : driver.getWindowHandles())  
 {  
 driver.switchTo().window(Child_Window);  
 //Perform operation on child window 
 driver.close();
 } 

 //Switching back to Parent Window  
 driver.switchTo().window(Parent_Window);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String window : allWindows) {
        if (!window.equals(parentWindow)) {
            String childWindow = window;
            driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
            driver.getCurrentlUrl(); // Child windows url link
        }
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow); // switching control to the parent window
    driver.getCurrentlUrl();  // Parent windows url link
    driver.close(); //closes the child window
    driver.quit(); //quits the driver
```

Answer (score -1):

try the below code.. it worked for me...

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.naukri.com/");

    //Get the address of main window
    String p = driver.getWindowHandle();

    //get address of all windows
    Set<String> allWH = driver.getWindowHandles();

    //get address of all windows and store it in ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> allWHCopy = new ArrayList<String>(allWH);

    //close the 2nd window
    for(int i=0;i<allWHCopy.size();i++)
    {
        if(i==2)
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(allWHCopy.get(i));
            driver.close();
        }
    }

    //To switch to main window
    driver.switchTo().window(p);

    //perform action in main window
}
```