# How to Handle Browser Popup (During the Download) using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

currently we scrap the data from Websites using Web driver (Selenium)with Java, during that Scrapping we need to do some download process (i.e XML file Download), let me know how will handle the Browser Popup (save As Dialog) using Java

```
<a href="javascript:downloadXML()">
    <img width="40" height="20" border="0" name="imag34" alt="Download" src="/pair/img/tabs/downloadxml.gif">
</a>
```

We are using the following code to click the above image

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[@alt='Download'])[3]")).click();
```

After clicking that image, it will open a "Save as.." popup. How do we go to that popup and do testing on that?

[image]

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620253/how-to-switch-control-from-child-window-to-parent-window-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Please show the code or screenshots. By "popup", some mean actual browser window, some mean iframe popup, some mean HTML div popup, some mean alerts. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Browser Popup during the Download, Like "Do you want to open or save file.xml"....

Comment: which browser ...u are targeting??? FF or IE or chrome??

Comment: target only in IE (version 9)

Answer (score 0):

This download popup is basically a window.open Javascript call with the URL of the XML file.
So this seems to be the relevant link :

[How to switch to the new browser window, which opens after click on the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/webdriver-switch-to-new-browser-opened-after-click-on-button)

Comment: first point - while clicking the "Download XML" Button not getting the URL, and second Point - that save popup was not a Parent and Child window,not able to find / trigger the element in that save popup, also i was tried with your option its seems not working

Comment: Try using Firebug tool in Firefox to find out what kind of WebElement this popup is.

Comment: this is for Browser popup, unable to inspect the element with firebug or developer tools

Comment: Check if any of this helps: http://opensource-soa.blogspot.in/2009/10/how-to-capture-pop-up-window-using.html

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this problem using the Robot class from Java. The Robot class allow you to simulate keybord press, in so doing you can work with TABs and Enters in order to execute the download.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a windows pop up and firebug will not able to detect this.If you are using windows OS then you can use AutoIT tool this will solve your problem.