# Selenium clicking to get large image from Amazon

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get the largest image size off a product page.  I can only view those src when I click on the first image.

No element is found, I have tried many different ids trying to get that pull up menu?  Any advice on how to do it in python?

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.amazon.com/ZITRADES-Waterproof-Modes-String-Lights/dp/B00EOHF3QG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1448949777&sr=8-1&keywords=B00EOHF3QG")
driver.find_element_by_id("leftCol").click()
```

Should extract:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71Ew-t9%2BHkL._SL1000_.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61bR9hPenCL._SL1000_.jpg, etc
```

Comment: Which image you want to get? main image or image which comes and zoom on mouse hover?

Comment: @HelpingHands I want to get all of the images.  However if I can hover over the first one always and click it then I think I can handle that frame and extract all large images from that.  Otherwise the urls are not the large images.

Comment: you want to click on all small thumbnail? which are left to main image?

Comment: @HelpingHands nope I can do that.  If you click the first image then another popup shows up a window and I want to handle that.  But I am having trouble clicking the first image for the window to pop up.

Comment: ok I got you , Actually that is child window , you have to switch to child window first to access those images.

Comment: See this will help you for switching : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620253/how-to-switch-control-from-child-window-to-parent-window-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @HelpingHands gotcha, I am unsure how to click it still to actually pull up the window.  I can handle it from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96641/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-test-dev).