# How to switch back to parent window in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to close a child window and switch back to the parent window to perform some operations.

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.example.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testUntitled2() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/info.php");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.fa.fa-facebook-sq")).click();
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }

    // Perform the actions on new window
    driver.close(); // This will close new opened window

    //driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore); // I need to perform below

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.fa.fa-twitter-square")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.fa.fa-google-plus-  squ)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.fa.fa-linkedin-square")).click();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch control from child window to parent window in selenium webdriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620253/how-to-switch-control-from-child-window-to-parent-window-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 2):

Create one `parentWindowHandle` String variable before `for` loop and store windowhandle there. Once you are done with your operation with child window, go back to that `parentWindowHandle`.

```
String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
/* You code to move to child window*/

//After you done with child window
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandle);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for switching to child window and then back to parent window.

Code:

```
   String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
            String subWindowHandler = null;

            Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
            Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
            }
            driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); 

*****perform operations on child window******************

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
```

I hope this will solve your problem