# how to switch from parent window to child window using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I need to close a child window and switch back to the parent window to perform some operations.

```
public static void nextTab() throws InterruptedException { 
    Set winSet = UIPage.getBaseWindow().getWindowHandles(); 
    List winList = new ArrayList(winSet); 
    String newTab = winList.get(winList.size() - 1); UIPage.getBaseWindow().switchTo().window(newTab);
    Thread.sleep(Constant.LONG_TIMEOUT_500); 
}

public static void prevTab() { 
    Set winSet = UIPage.getBaseWindow().getWindowHandles(); 
    List winList = new ArrayList(winSet); 
    UIPage.getBaseWindow().close(); 
    String oldTab = winList.get(winList.size() - 2); //System.out.println(oldTab);
    UIPage.getBaseWindow().switchTo().window(oldTab);    
}
```

Comment: please, format the source code

Comment: I think below link might useful for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620253/how-to-switch-control-from-child-window-to-parent-window-in-selenium-webdriver?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

`//Get the main window handle`

`String mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();`

Now perform operation which opens child window like clicking on a link or button.

`//Switch to child window and close it`

```
for (String childWindowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
  //If window handle is not main window handle then close it 
  if(!childWindowHandle.equals(mainWindowHandle)){
  driver.switchTo().window(childWindowHandle);
  // Close child windows
  driver.close(); 
  }
} 

//switch back to main window
driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);
```

Comment: This is working but its is open two time both parent or child window . Inside for loop i want call child window only one time .plz help

Comment: Hi Ram Kishore, Updated code to close only child window. Take a look and let me know if this doensn't work.

Comment: Hi Prudhvi, Updated code is not working. if i run this code all current & main window are closed.plz help...

Comment: how to switching from 2nd child to 1st child window ?plz help.

Comment: Hi Kishore, Can you please add a print statement before for loop and in for loop and send me those results