# Selenium opens new window on click on add file button

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am doing following scenario, It behaves different when executed manually and through automation

steps: 
1. Click on upload
2. Select xml File
3. click on add

result when executed manually:
File uploaded successfully

result when executed through Automation:
New window opens with url: http://url/HttpProxyServletAction=AddAnduserId=username&passwordFileName="filepath.xml" and file doesnot get added

Even if I just open IE with selenium and try to add manually same issue occures. Is it a issue with capabilities? How to Solve this?

Answer (score 1):

can you provide the error log?
because from where i understood you are switching windows and when you switch window from parent window to child window you code does not knows what needs to be done.
you can refer to this question , which can give you an idea on how parent and child windows should be managed in selenium.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14620253/7820277])!

Comment: There is some confusion here. I dont want to switch windows. My question is if i open browser manually and click on add button (add button is on my webpage) it uploads file without opening new IE window. but if I open my browser through selenium and click on add button it opens new window and doesnot upload file. I want selenium behaves same way as manual.

Comment: can you show the code ? and also exception(if any) so that it could be easier to give an answer