# [1539589346.326][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the below Error while handling multiple windows in selenium
i.e : "`[1539589346.326][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer`".
But all my scripts are getting passed but error message is displaying.

below steps:

1. Navigate to parent window to child window
2. When click on a button in child window and child window will
   automatically closed (Functionality)
3. Now I am switching to parent Window.

So. Please any one can help me?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials, relevant _HTML_ and code trials.

Answer (score 0):

There is method with the named getWindowHandle() will works on such cases.
i hope this will work for you.

```
String old = driver.getWindowHandle();
for (String w : _driver.getWindowHandles()) {
   // Switch to child 
   driver.switchTo().window(w);
 }
String new = driver.getWindowHandle();
// no need to do driver.close(); as automatically get closed.

driver.switchto.window(old);
```

possible duplicate of [How to switch control from child window to parent window in selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620253/how-to-switch-control-from-child-window-to-parent-window-in-selenium-webdriver)